Detaching two sub-captions attached to each other
I would like to understand why, after creating two subfigures with appropriate commands (albeit with TikZ), the sub-captions remain pasted to each other.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}      \usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{bending} 
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.50\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
    \draw [line width=0.1mm](-2.8,0) -- (2.8,0);
    \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=gray!20, ultra thick](0,1)coordinate(D) circle [radius=1];
    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,0)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-1.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
    \fill (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(0.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,2)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
    \fill (0,2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \fill (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \fill (-1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Schematizzazione dell'accelerazione di trascinamento del centro di massa nel moto di pura traslazione.}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.50\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
    \draw [line width=0.1mm](-2.8,0) -- (2.8,0);
    \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=gray!20, ultra thick](0,1)coordinate(D) circle [radius=1];
    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (-1,1) --(-1,0) node[yshift=3ex,xshift=-5ex, above] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (0,2) --(-1,2) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (0,0) --(1,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
    \fill (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (1,1) --(1,2) node[yshift=-3ex,xshift=5ex,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
    \fill (0,2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \fill (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \fill (-1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Schematizzazione dell'accelerazione relativa lineare istantanea dei punti periferici della ruota nel moto di pura rotazione attorno al centro di massa.}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}

Adding or removing \hfill does not change the result. Is there a way for the two sub-captions to be detached, each for its own subfigure?

o.5\textwidth + 0.5\textwidth + space exceeds \textwidth. You could comment out the space, but \hfill would only be zero, so the captions will touch. You need to make the subfigures a bit narrower and, once that is done, you find you need to make the tikzpictures a bit smaller, too. Although I've just reduced the scale factor here, note that scaling your pictures is not a great approach and it isn't at all clear why you are using this method here.
\documentclass{article}% guessed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% unneeded for a couple of decades
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
% \usepackage{blindtext}% not for real documents
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{pgf}% loaded by tikz
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage{tikz}% loaded by tikz-cd
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% should be loaded later - probably last
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% consider passing a4paper as a class option
% \usepackage{graphicx}% loaded by tikz
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}% does this work with deprecated arrow tips?
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.35]
        \draw [line width=0.1mm](-2.8,0) -- (2.8,0) coordinate (a);
        \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=gray!20, ultra thick](0,1)coordinate(D) circle [radius=1];
       ,baseline=(a \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,0)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-1.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
        \fill (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(0.5,1)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->] ($(-0.5,2)+(.5,0)$) -- +(0.75,0) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{A}_{\color{black}{1}}$};
        \fill (0,2) circle[radius=1pt];
        \fill (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \fill (-1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \subcaption{Schematizzazione dell'accelerazione di trascinamento del centro di massa nel moto di pura traslazione.}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.35]
        \draw [line width=0.1mm](-2.8,0) -- (2.8,0) coordinate (b);
        \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=gray!20, ultra thick](0,1)coordinate(D) circle [radius=1];
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (-1,1) --(-1,0) node[yshift=3ex,xshift=-5ex, above] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
        \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (0,2) --(-1,2) node[midway,above] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
        \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (0,0) --(1,0) node[midway,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
        \fill (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[ultra thick,cyan,->] (1,1) --(1,2) node[yshift=-3ex,xshift=5ex,below] {\large $\boldsymbol{a}_{\text{relativa}}$};
        \fill (0,2) circle[radius=1pt];
        \fill (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \fill (-1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \subcaption{Schematizzazione dell'accelerazione relativa lineare istantanea dei punti periferici della ruota nel moto di pura rotazione attorno al centro di massa.}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}

